# automaticly insert text in input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way that if someone enters a site, everything that he writes will be entered in an input automatically so he doesn't need to click on it?

If already searched in the Internet, but I found nothing.

Comment: Yes, there's a way.

Comment: Why do you expect your user to arrive on your site and start typing without focusing an `<input>`?

Comment: You need to set focus on the input element with javascript on page load.

Comment: Please provide more details about your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add focus to your input by below line.

```
document.getElementById('search').focus();
```

See Demo

```js
document.getElementById('search').focus();
```

```html
<input id="search">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's the way I think:

```
document.querySelector('#your-input-id').focus();
```